# Why descendingSet smaller than original set?

Tags: java, collections, set

I have a collection with 191 elements:

```
NavigableSet<Taxon> _set = new ConcurentSkipListSet<>();
...
_set.size(); // 191
_set.descendingSet().size(); // also 191
_set.descendingSet().toArray().length; // 53
_set.toArray().length; // 191
```

Taxon.java:

```
class Taxon implements Comparable<Taxon> {

    public final int x;
    public final int y;
    public final int r;
    public final List<Long> ips;

    public Taxon(int x, int y, int r, List<Long> ips) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
        this.ips = ips;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Taxon o) {
        return this.ips.size() > o.ips.size() ? 1 : -1;
    }

}
```

Why _sel.descendingSet().toArray() is smaller? When I iterate _sel.descendingSet() it's breaken on 53 element. How to iterate whole descending collection?

**UPDATE**
I am sure there no modification on this set, during check

Comment: Unless this is a typo, there seems to no reason why the length should reduce when the Set is converted to any Array. Check if this is applicable in your case: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html#size()

Comment: I don't think this is all your real code. Also, since you have a `ConcurrentSkipListSet`, it may be modified by another thread between `_set.descendingSet().size();` and `_set.descendingSet().toArray().length;` which would be a valid result.

Comment: Can you compare to the ascending toArray(). It sounds like your collection is corrupt.  Perhaps your `compareTo()` is broken in some way.

Comment: I doubt we can answer your question without a valid code sample. Please post your code as an [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Hope you might be or your code might be changing the real set, _set in between your calculation of set size and set array size.. Please check. Do you have own comparator in converting to descending set?

Comment: Yes, I have my own comparator, but How it can be affect?

Comment: Post the code of your custom `Comparator`. The problem lies that some values are considered *equals* when they should be different.

Comment: @mystdeim check your comparator. Better way would be run you program in debug mode and check for each values returned from comparator. Then you find out the working of you comparator.

Comment: @mystdeim the compareTo should return -1 or 0 or 1. Why are you returning -1? any reason?

Comment: Your comparator has no case for equality.

Comment: I know, but how it can affect on length?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to wrong implementation of compareTo() method. 
CompareTo() contract is not followed here.

Contract states that if x.comparedTo(y) == -(y.comparedTo(x)). Lets consider following example
suppose we have following objects for class Taxon with their insertion order as described below

```
insertion order for Taxon   ips List size 
taxon0                      3
taxon1                      1
taxon2                      1
taxon3                      3
taxon4                      1
```

taxon0.comparedTo(taxom3) is -1 and taxon3.compareTo(taxon0) is also -1. Means taxon0 is smaller than taxom3 and taxom3 is smaller than taxom0 which is wrong.

_set.descendingSet().size() and _set.descendingSet().toArray().length returns different results because _set.descendingSet().toArray() method internally use iterator to get current snapshot of the set. Iterator internally uses compareTo() method to iterate over the set. size() method does not use iterator and just count the number of elements.Hence both of them have different return values.

ConcurrentSkipListSet arranges its elements as sorted by their natural ordering or based on Comparator. When we add taxom objects into ConcurrentSkipListSet, they are arranged in the following order (skipping index node here)

Head -> taxon4 -> taxon2 -> taxon1 -> taxon3 -> taxon0 -> null

_set.descendingSet().toArray().length set pointer at taxon0 and after that taxom0.comparedTo(taxon3) returns -1.
Hence iterator decides that taxom0 is before taxom3 and taxom3 is skipped during iteration. Iterator comes to know that 
taxom1 precedes taxom0. After that pointer shifts to taxom1 and like wise taxon1 is compared to taxom4(not taxom2 due to skip list algorithm, down and right pointers) and taxom1.comparedTo(taxom4) says that taxom1 is smaller than taxom4 which contradicts actual arrangement and pointer moves to head. Hence Iterator return only two elements.

Here we have 2 kinds on length for ips List 1,3. Hence only two elements. In your example, you may have 91 kinds of different lengths ips list. All the duplicates are skipped due to compareTo() method.

You can add more attributes in compareTo() method to decide natural ordering of Taxon as per your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer to iterate whole descending collection.
Convert it into list and now you can easily iterate over it...:)

```
 List<Taxon> taxonList = new ArrayList<Taxon>(_set);
 System.out.println(taxonList.size());
 int size = taxonList.size();
 for(int i = size-1; i<=0; i--)
  {
     System.out.println(taxonList.get(i));
  }
```